# Which element was pressed-JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I've created an array of "books".

```
ArrayList<Gradivo> poljeGradiv = new ArrayList<Gradivo>();
        poljeGradiv = (ArrayList<Gradivo>) session.getAttribute("poljeGradiv");
```

Which will be displayed this way

```
for(int i=0; i<poljeGradiv.size();i++){
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick="podrobniPrikaz.jsp"><%=poljeGradiv.get(i).getNaslov() %></a></td>
                <td><%=poljeGradiv.get(i).getAvtor() %></td>
            </tr>
            <%
        }
```

The "a" tag was just me trying things out. Pressing one "book" should send me to another page, with more information about it. But how do i know which one was pressed. I can't get the specific book out of the ArrayList if i don't know which one it was. Is there a way to do this without JQuery (we haven't taken it yet, so it's not suppose to be used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass id (or some kind of unique attribute) of the book to podrobniPrikaz.jsp. I assume your book class has a method getId() which returns unique id.

```
<td><a onclick="podrobniPrikaz.jsp?bookId=<%=poljeGradiv.get(i).getId()%>"><%=poljeGradiv.get(i).getNaslov() %></a></td>
```

In podrobniPrikaz.jsp you can get the value of bookId via:

```
request.getParameter("bookId");
```

so you know which one is clicked.

Comment: I should've known that's how you can pass attributes. Thanks